# difference between "to share in" and "to share"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The following is part of a Washington Post article of today.

> This may be Obama’s military intervention, but if she is a candidate in 2016, Clinton could share in whatever credit or blame the public assigns to his decisions.

Is there any difference in the meaning or nuance between

> *share in whatever credit or blame* and
>   *share whatever credit or blame* (without *in*) ?

Comment: To me `to share` means there's a limited about of something that's being partitioned. I don't think they mean that Clinton would take away some credit/blame. `Share in` means that one could get a portion of something without affecting the quantity that the President could get.

Comment: To *share* something means you have some and you are giving some to others.  To share *in* something means that somebody else has some and is giving some to you.

Comment: This question probably belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) because it is about communication in everyday English, and is not about the academic study of English Language.

Comment: @Jim That's misleading. Your defimition for _share_ covers only one sense. Look at sense two at AHD: share 1  ...
v. shared, shar·ing, shares
v.tr.
1. To divide and parcel out in shares; apportion.
2. To participate in, use, enjoy, or experience jointly or in turns.... >> The meanings of _share_ and _share in_ overlap (though see user814064's comment for subtle differences in connotation); likewise, the meanings of _share_ and _share out_ overlap.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- I dunno, I think it works perfectly here.  The public is handing out credit or blame and Clinton can share in that.  IF it were changed to read *Clinton could share whatever credit or blame...* I would take that as Clinton pointing out others to redirect some of the credit or blame originally assigned to her.

Answer (score 1):

In the context provided, "to share in" means that she will have her share in the blame or credit that comes from Obama's decisions, while "to share" would mean that she would share "the credit or blame."